# Remove "/public" from Laravel route

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

I have the project URL as -

```
http://localhost/project-name/user/public/xxx
```

I want to change it to -

```
http://localhost/project-name/user/xxx
```

I have tried the usual solution available on internet but still no luck. These are htaccess files after going through few solution.

**1. project-name/.htaccess**

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On
# Check what redirect trailing slash does
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

**2. project-name/public/.htaccess**

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

What is the exact solution for this problem?

Comment: Where are you deploying? Have you tried creating a VirtualHost pointing to your ```public``` directory?

Comment: I don't have the permission to do so. Can I achieve the same using htaccess only?

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have permissions to point virtual host to your laravel public folder, I would suggest you:

For Laravel 5, 1) move all your files in the public folder into project root, public folder is not needed anymore and 2) update the original index.php like so:

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

For Laravel 4, you also need to edit value of "public" in the array in /bootstrap/paths.php.

This should achieve what you want. Hopes this helps.

Having said that, try to host your app in VPS where you have full control on everything :)

Comment: The files inside the ```bootstrap``` should also be fixed. I cannot find the blog post I used some time ago to deploy on a shared hosting, but this one should clarify a little bit https://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host

Comment: That's the case of Laravel 4. From 5.0, you don't have to modify files in bootstrap folder anymore.

Comment: Well, I believe there is a ```laravel-4``` tag, so I suppose the author is using version 4 :)